# "The beach was flat enough to play soccer on." or "The beach was flat enough to play soccer."

Tags: prepositions, to-infinitive

- The beach was flat enough to play soccer on.

This sentence is from my English grammar book.  I understand why there is an "on" at the end of the sentence, but I still wonder if the sentence below would be wrong.

- The beach was flat enough to play soccer.

Comment: @YosefBaskin And 'it' in "the trophy wouldn't fit in the suitcase because it was too big" could refer to the suitcase. Just because something is technically syntactically valid doesn't mean anyone would actually interpret it that way, brains or no.

Comment: The wrong quality of #2 is simply that someone could be literal enough to misinterpret it. "The beach was flat enough to play soccer" to the wrong ears means that the beach itself could play soccer because it was flat. A bumpy beach, no. Right. Like "The boy was old enough to attend school."

Answer (score 2):

Either sentence is correct. In some situations, prepositions can be left out if there is no other preposition that makes sense. We wouldn't be playing soccer inside the beach or over the beach or under the beach, for example. So it's okay to include or leave off the preposition **on**.